# Calling a hibernate-command from python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have a python script which shall call a system call to hibernate the system(Ubuntu-Server). I try

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

 import os 
 os.system('pm-hibernate')
```

If I run this without sudo-rights, I get the right error:

```
This utility may only be run by the root user.
```

But when calling this script with sudo-rights nothing happen.
How to call a hibernate-command out of python?

Comment: `os.system("sudo ...")` and make sudo not to ask for password.

Comment: how are you giving sudo rights?

Comment: o.o it was this easy way :) only write a sudo in front of and the it works. I thouht it is enough to call the script with `sudo ./script.py`

Answer (score 1):

Run it with sudo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(['sudo', '/usr/sbin/pm-hibernate'])
```

and configure the user that runs this script to be allowed to run `pm-hibernate` without a password e.g., create `/etc/sudoer.d/pm-hibernate` file and write `%admin ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/pm-hibernate` in it (`sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/pm-hibernate`).

Make sure `/etc/sudoers` imports `/etc/sudoers.d` directory (`sudo visudo`) and `/etc/sudoer.d/pm-hibernate` file has `0440` permissions:

```
$ sudo chmod 0440 /etc/sudoer.d/pm-hibernate
```

see also `sudo less /etc/sudoers.d/README`.

The command allows all members of `admin` group to run `sudo pm-hibernate` without a password. Run `groups`, to see the groups you belong.

Comment: I see your solution, but `check_call` cannot execute this command, because `pm-hibernate` don't return a 0 exit status. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError

Comment: @alabamajack: [I know what `check_call()` does](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsubprocess%5D+user%3A4279+is%3Aanswer). The intent is to avoid hiding an error: `import this` -- [Errors should never pass silently.  Unless explicitly silenced.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) Does `pm-hibernate` even return on success (on the next power on)? what status does it return on success? You could use `subprocess.call([..]) != success_status: raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(...)`